# Proving that $x^n=a$, for $n>0$ an odd natural number, has exactly one real root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

In my school book, I read this theorem

> Let $n>0$ is an odd natural number (or an odd positive integer), then the equation $$x^n=a$$ has exactly one real root.

But, the book doesn't provide a proof, only tells $x=\sqrt [n]a$.
How can I prove this theorem?

I tried to prove some special cases

$$x^3=8$$
$$(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)=0$$
$$x=2 \vee x^2+2x+4=0$$

But the Discriminant of $x^2+2x+4=0$ equals to $2^2-4×4=-12<0$. So $x=2$ is an only root. But for $x^5=32$, I got $x=2$ and $x^4+2x^3+4x^2+8x+16=0$.

I don't know how I can proceed.

Comment: $x\mapsto x^n$ is strictly increasing and injective when $n$ is an odd natural integer. It can only cross a certain point once

Comment: @FShrike Beat me to it. To OP: sketch the graph of the function y=x^n-a

Comment: @FShrike If $x<0$ how do you get $x\mapsto x^n$ is strictly increasing?

Comment: Use Mark’s argument, or, just differentiate @nonstudent

Comment: @FShrike  Thanks. But, I still didn't get a point...How do you derive the this result: strictly increasing, for $x<0$?

Comment: @nonstudent $x<y<0\implies x^n=-|x|^n<-|y|^n=y^n<0$

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "How can I prove the following theorem?" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Answer (score 2):

To prove this you can do the following to show that the function $y=x^n$ is increasing when $n$ is odd.

So suppose $a\gt b$ and $n$ is odd, we want to prove $a^n\gt b^n$. Well if $a\gt 0 \gt b$ then you are adding the positive terms $a^n$ and $-b^n$. Else $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots b^{n-1}\right)$$

Here $a-b$ is positive by hypothesis and every term $a^rb^{n-1-r}$ is non-negative because $n$ is odd and $a$ and $b$ do not have opposite signs (one of them could be zero). Finally since $a\gt b$ we have $a\neq b$ so that either $a^{n-1}$ or $b^{n-1}$ is positive (non zero) so $a^n-b^n$ is the product of two strictly positive numbers and is positive.

Comment: Note, you really also need to know $x^n$ is unbounded in both directions to get that there is always a root.

Comment: "Both terms are positive?" What terms? I think you mean something else.

Comment: do you mean $a > b > 0$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have clarified this

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan I am dealing at the end with the two cases $a\gt b\gt 0$ and $0\gt a \gt b$. If they are both negative then $a^2, ab, b^2, a^5b^3 \cdots $ are all positive (multiplying together an even number of negative factors).

Answer (score 1):

We can assume wlog $x$ and $a$ both positive such that $x^n=a$ indeed

$$x^n=a \iff (-x)^n =(-1)^nx^n =-a$$

Then assume by contradiction $\exists y>0 \; y\neq x$ such that $y^n=a$ then

$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\ldots xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})=0$$

which is impossible, that is $x^n$ is injective.

Therefore it suffices to show that at least one solution exists and it follows from [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) using that $x^n$ is continuous with $x^n=0$ at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^n = \infty$, that is $x^n$ is also surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even then $x^n=a$ has two real roots, $x=\pm\sqrt[n]{a}$, since $x^n=\left(x^{(n/2)}\right)^2$ is always positive, but solutions are restricted to $a\geq0$. If $n$ is odd then $x^n=a$ does not have the negative root $x=-\sqrt[n]{a}$ since $(-\sqrt[n]{a})^n=(-1)^n (\sqrt[n]{a})^n=-a\neq a$. It may also have solutions when $a$ is negative.

One can prove uniqueness of the solution to $\sqrt
[n]{a}$ using properties of the real numbers.  If there is a number such that $b^n=(\sqrt[n]{a})^n=a$ then $(\sqrt[n]{a})^{-n}b^n=1$ thus $b\sqrt[n]{a}=1$ and by uniqueness of inverse $b=\sqrt[n]{a}$. (If $n$ is even you also need to take into account negative roots.)

Comment: The step "thus" uses what you want to prove, so it seems.

Comment: You can only go to $\sqrt[n]{a}/b =\sqrt[n]{1}$, how do you evaluate the righthand side to 1 without assuming what you want to prove?

Comment: Your last comment shows the problem: "If n is even you also need to take into account negative roots." how do you know you don't have to take other roots into account for odd n? That's the thing you are trying to prove...

Comment: Stated in another way: the "thus" part fails for even n because x^n=1 has more than one real solution for even n. How do you know that it works for odd n? How do you know that there is a unique solution? That's exactly what you are trying to prove, so you should not just assume that it's true.

Comment: I'm sorry that you think it's ridiculous, but it is generally accepted that you should not assume the thing you are trying to prove.

Answer (score 0):

The case $a=0$ is obviously trivial. Suppose that $a>0$. This implies $x^n>0\implies x>0$, where $n$ is an odd positive integer.

Thus, we can apply the *real-valued* logarithm rules to the both sides:

$$
\begin{aligned}x^n=a,\,a>0
&\implies \ln x^n =\ln a\\
&\implies n \ln x= \ln a\\
&\implies \ln x =\frac {\ln a}{n}\\
&\implies x=e^{\frac {\ln a}{n}}\end{aligned}$$

Then, note that $f(x)=e^x$ is an exponential function. By properties of the real-valued exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ is strictly increasing function and the value of $e^x$ is an unique. This implies that, the value of $e^{\frac {\ln a}{n}}$ is unique.

On the other hand,

$$
\begin{aligned}x=\left(e^{\ln a}\right)^{\frac 1n}=a^{\frac 1n}=\sqrt [n]{a}.\end{aligned}
$$

Then suppose that, $a<0$. Since $n$ is an odd positive integer, we have:

$$
\begin{aligned} x^n=a\iff(-x)^n=-a>0 \end{aligned}
$$

Now applying the same logarithm rules, we get

$$-x=e^{\frac {\ln (-a)}{n}}\implies x=-e^{\frac {\ln (-a)}{n}}$$

This means, value of $-e^{\frac {\ln (-a)}{n}}$ is also unique.

On the other hand,

$$
\begin{aligned}
(-x)^n=-a,\,-a>0&\implies (-x)=\sqrt [n]{-a}\\
&\implies -x=-\sqrt [n]{a}\\
&\implies x=\sqrt[n]{a}.\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Aren't we shifting the original problem to the inverse function $\sqrt [n]{x}$ in this way?